Are there any methods to send trigger notifications via email from Looker Studio?
I’m working on a project using Looker Studio to create dashboards, and I want to implement a feature that automatically sends an email to people when certain numbers exceed a specified threshold.
I am actually still find out if it's a thing but I don't get much any information on the internet.

Unfortunately Looker studio does not currently support automatic email or notification triggers based on specific thresholds, all is not lost because other tools do. You best bet is to get a paid for tool like Zapier that will have the capability built in. If you are looking for a cheaper option Google sheets with the aid of Apps Script should be able to do it.
